# are deleted comments recorded in responses tab?

Tags: support, questions, comments, notifications, responses

If i do @Tom and create a comment, but delete the comment before Tom reads it, is it still listed in his "responses" tab?

My previous question https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91939/how-to-notifications-work is closed as a duplicate and got -10 votes (for what reason i don't know?!) although the answer for that question could not be found in the "duplicate thread".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but it is listed in the global inbox (the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™).

Comment: +1, but you missed a TM on MultiCollider

Comment: @davidsleeps MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ is one term, and not two. Just search for the term here on MSO search and you'll see that MultiCollider is never ™ed.

Comment: @waiwai933, then I'll feature request it...

Comment: this is not actually true; some comments can slip through if they are created and deleted very rapidly but in general comment deletions do propagate back to the global inbox.

Comment: thank you people. finally someone understood my question. my exact question at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91939/how-to-notifications-work got -10 downvotes for i don't know what reason?

Comment: @Pacerier: One reason might be that your original title didn't describe your question _at all_. (Another reason, but that only adds to it: Downvotes on questions are now free.)

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt comon, just a typo mistake and there's such a huge vote difference in 2 exact same questions?!

Comment: @Pacerier: I have no idea what you mean by "typo mistake". Wait, I _do_ have an idea: Do you mean you typed that title _accidentally?_ If yes, then I can't follow you.

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt its a Ctrl-C Ctrl-V typo mistake understand now?

Comment: @Pacerier: Now I understand it better. But I still wonder a bit why you didn't see that immediately. (By the way, although I do see other issues with that question, I wouldn't vote it down, now that the title is fixed.)

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt because that ask-question-page loves to "jump" automatically i easily miss it